# laravel-jsvalidation not using all rules

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

I'm using laravel-jsValidation, https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation and my problem is that only the first rule in my list of rules is used.

In example below, the js will halt submit only if 'title' field is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

No errors whatsoever, backend or javascript.

Laravel v.5.1

/christian

Rules:

```
    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
        'company_id' => 'required|int',
        'primary_site' => 'required|int',
        'application_type' => 'required|int',
        ];
```

And in controller method:

```
        $validator = \JsValidator::make($this->rules);

    return view('form', array(
        'person' => $person,
        'validator' => $validator,
        ));
```

The javascript that is rendered in my view seems ok:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $("form").validate({
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'help-block error-help-block',

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length ||
                element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                // else just place the validation message immediatly after the input
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the Bootstrap error class to the control group
        },


        /*
         // Uncomment this to mark as validated non required fields
         unhighlight: function(element) {
         $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
         },
         */
        success: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // remove the Boostrap error class from the control group
        },

        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
                    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {

            if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
                return;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            $(validator.errorList[0].element).focus();

        },

        rules: {"title":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"F\u00e4ltet title \u00e4r obligatoriskt.",true],["Max",["255"],"title f\u00e5r max inneh\u00e5lla 255 tecken.",false]]},"body":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"F\u00e4ltet body \u00e4r obligatoriskt.",true]]},"company_id":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"F\u00e4ltet company id \u00e4r obligatoriskt.",true],["Integer",[],"company id m\u00e5ste vara en siffra.",false]]},"primary_site":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"F\u00e4ltet primary site \u00e4r obligatoriskt.",true],["Integer",[],"primary site m\u00e5ste vara en siffra.",false]]},"application_type":{"laravelValidation":[["Required",[],"F\u00e4ltet application type \u00e4r obligatoriskt.",true],["Integer",[],"application type m\u00e5ste vara en siffra.",false]]}}        })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is in your $rules section. 'int' it written as integer in Laravel. Maybe this is causing errors you can't see?

As for the documentation on available and correct validation rules in Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Ok, thanks, tried that but no success. 

And now I see that the validation does not work if I only use 'application_type' => 'required|integer' - it only works on the title key... perhaps this is a clue?

Comment: Hmm interesting, I must say I do not really understand the JS code. Might be just an typo somewhere, but I can't tell. I myself use JqueryValidation, It's around the same amount of code, but much clearer/easier. It does not use the validation rules of the laravel validator though, but I don't know if that is a requirement of you.
Docs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/